# Common Lisp - Error between function : Undefined operator get-param in form (get-param :mem)

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm in LispWorks, I see other question with this title but none of them helped me.

This is the code I write:

```
(defun get-param (param)
  (lambda (state)
    (getf (cdr state) param)))

(defconstant get-acc
  (get-param ':acc))
(defconstant get-pc
  (get-param ':pc))
```

The caller from code give me the error in the title.

```
(defun add-instruction (xx state)
    (let* ((acc (funcall get-acc state))
             (new-acc (mod (+ acc xx) 1000))
             (new-flag (> 999 (+ acc xx)))
             (new-pc (+ 1 (funcall get-pc state)))
             (list 'state ':acc new-acc ':pc new-pc ':mem (funcall get-mem state))))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the call `(funcall get-acc state)` which is the value of state?

Comment: its a list of the form  '(state :acc 10 :pc 0 :mem (1 2 3 4 5)) , for example.
But i have this error when i load the function in the repl without calling that

Comment: In CCL the call returns correctly the value 10.

Comment: Are you loading the call from a file with just that line? Since the error seems caused by a definition that includes `(get-param :mem)`.

Comment: i include all the function call in the answer

Comment: I Edit the question

Comment: The `get-mem` definition is missing (and the function `add-instruction` has a `let` with a null body). Maybe you should close a parenthesis after the line before `list`.

Comment: Thanks and Sorry: I miss the definition of get-mem while copy the code and the i put a the parenthesis in the wrong place now this works fine. Thank you again!

Comment: Note that it is basically pointless to have your `get-x` constants because they don’t hide anything because you still explicitly construct states in various functions. Either make a `state` class or struct, or just pass around your state as a raw plots and maybe put the property names into constants instead.